# Remove site title and site description if a custom logo has been set - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I remove both the site-title and site-description once a custom logo has been set?

I have added the option to choose a custom logo in the Wordpress customizer but now I'm struggling with the php trying to hide both the title and description.

The piece of code at the bottom regarding the description should, in some way, be added to the if/else statement which already removes the site-title but I'm not sure how.

```
<div class="site-branding">
        <?php
        if(the_custom_logo) {
            the_custom_logo();
        }   elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) { ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
        <?php
        }
```

EDIT:
The code above removes the site-title once a custom logo has been set.

Below is the code that covers the site-description. I'm not sure in what way I should alter this piece of code to tell it to get lost when a custom logo has been set just like the site-title.

```
        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
        <?php
        } ?>
    </div><!-- .site-branding -->
```

So in short: The site should show either the logo or the title + description.

I'm still very new to php any help or advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I really appreciate the help so far but I seem to have given you the wrong idea. I already got my custom logo to work. I can add and save it in the customizer without problems and I also got it to replace the site-title on the website. So getting the logo to replace the site-title is not The problem. I also want it to replace the site-description (so the logo replaces both title and description) that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_custom_logo()` when you want to print/echo the results. Use `get_custom_logo()` when you want to return the results (for instance, when you want to assign it to a variable or use in a conditional).

```
<?php
    if( get_custom_logo() ) {
        the_custom_logo();
    } elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        ?>
        <h1 class="site-title">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
        </h1>
        <?php
        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    } else {
        ?>
        <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
        <?php
        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    }

    if ( ( isset($description) && $description) || is_customize_preview() ) {
        ?>
        <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ezra for the comment but the logo is not the issue. I got that working. I'm just struggling with removing both the site-title and description. The code ate the bottom covers the description I just have to add it (or part of it) to the if else statement above but Im not sure how.

Comment: @Marrrc okay I've adjusted the above accordingly.

Comment: That's it! Thanks Ezra!

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but you have a contradicting statement.

```
} elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
```

is_front_page() is used when you have set a page to be your home page and is_home() is used to identify the blog page.

using:

```
} elseif ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
```

might suit what your are trying to achieve better.

EDITED:

```
    <?php
    $logoSet = the_custom_logo();
    if($logoSet) {
        the_custom_logo();
    }   elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) { ?>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
    <?php
    }

    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
        <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
    <?php
    } ?>
```

Comment: Hey christopher I get what you mean, makes sense. That's actually the way it was prepared by the _underscores theme I haven't touched it. I'll change it just to see what happens but I might leave it as it is. Thanks though!

Comment: another suggestion. Try setting the_custom_logo to a variable edited above